# Select and save the value from the CoreData entity using Picker (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui, picker

I have a SwiftUI app, which uses CoreData to store the data. I use the @FetchRequest to load the data in a View.

I want to choose an entity from CoreData storage «Aircraft» using default Picker, and save user’s choice to another storage ("Flight").

At the moment I’m totally lost and have no idea how to make the Picker functional.

1. What should I put on the «selection» field of the Picker?
2. How I can access the specific value of the model in Text label of the Picker's cell (for example, show in label the String with the registration of the aircraft (var «registration» in my class)? I’ve tried many options like

> Text("(aircraft.registration ?? "Unknown")")

, but all of them give the wrong reference and subsequent compiling error.

Here is my complete code of the View:

```
struct PickerView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(entity: Aircraft.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var aircrafts: FetchedResults<Aircraft>
    @State private var selectedAircraft = "" // should I use it here? 

    var body: some View {
        Picker("Select aircraft", selection: self.$selectedAircraft) { // here i'm lost. I want to display registration String on my Picker


            ForEach(aircrafts, id: \.self) {aircraft in
                Text("\(aircraft.registration ?? "Unknown")") // obviously I'm doing something wrong here 

                Button("Save") {
                    let newFlight = Flight(context: self.moc)
                    newFlight.aircraft = self.selectedAircraft // not sure if i'm using correct logic here to save the registration string to to the Flight entity

                    try? self.moc.save()
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my class Flight (automatically generated based on CoreData entity model):

```
extension Aircraft {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Aircraft> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Aircraft>(entityName: "Aircraft")
    }

    @NSManaged public var aircraftClass: String?
    @NSManaged public var aircraftModel: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var registration: String?

}
```

And here is my class Aircraft (automatically generated based on CoreData entity model):

```
extension Flight {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Flight> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Flight>(entityName: "Flight")
    }

    @NSManaged public var aircraft: String? // we are interested to store the value from picker here
    @NSManaged public var flightDuration: Double
    @NSManaged public var from: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var remark: String?
    @NSManaged public var timeIn: String?
    @NSManaged public var timeOut: String?
    @NSManaged public var to: String?
    @NSManaged public var totalTime: Double


}
```